# How can I collapse data in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongodb with pymongo and I wanted to ask if there is a way to collapse data within mongodb. So I have data which is identified by user_ids and date and I want to count and average the occurrences of all existing combinations. For example user 123 created x comments on day y.
Is there an easy way to do this?

My data looks like this

```
{ "date" : 1310039769, "from_id" : 139920955, "value" : 123 }
{ "date" : 1310039769, "from_id" : 139920955, "value" : 242 }
{ "date" : 1310039770, "from_id" : 139920955, "value" : 242 }
```

...

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/

Comment: @AlexBlex Thanks!